# javascript - sound is not playing in browser

Tags: javascript, audio

I am using this code to play sounds, but sounds are playing just in Adobe Dreamweaver, not in browsers.
thanks for any help :)

```
var audio1 = new Audio('sound1.mp3');
var audio2 = new Audio('sound2.mp3');

var audio3 = new Audio('sound3.mp3');
var audio4 = new Audio('sound4.mp3');


function sound1()
{
        audio1.play();
}
function sound2()
{
        audio2.play();
}
function sound3()
{
        audio3.play();
}
function sound4()
{
        audio4.play();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked through the browser's developer tools that the files are actually loading properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions that play each sound aren't getting called. Try something like:

```
sound1();
```

to play the first sound

Comment: they are called in another page